# Simulink: Specifying trajectory

Tags: matlab, path, simulink

I would like to use jtraj to specify a trajectory in a Simulink model. Below are what I attempted to retrieve in the command prompt:

```
Q0 = [1 1 0];
Q1 = [1+0.5*cos(2*20) 1+0.5*sin(2*20) 0];
t = 0:0.1:20;
[Q, Qd, Qdd] = jtraj(Q0, Q1, t);
```

However, I don't know how to include such trajectory data in the Simulink model easily. Any comments?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to import some time-dependent data as a signal in a Simulink model, correct?  There are two ways you can do this,

1. Using a root inport, and then importing the data using the Input field on the Data Import/Export page of the configuration parameters.  See the [documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/simulink/ug/f11-46817.html) for more information.
2. Use a [From Workspace](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/simulink/slref/fromworkspace.html) block to import the data from the base workspace.

Comment: That's exactly what I used (the second case).

Answer (score 0):

i think there is some ways:
you can write your data to m-file (for example by test.m name)
then befor running simulink model, you can run this m-file,
in this case you can use Constant block whit variable's name that exists to workspace.